# 240sec Registering New Account with Services

Tags: 7, services

I am working with a fresh copy of Services 7.x-3.4 / user resource enabled.

A POST to api/user/register is made with Content-Type header application/json and body:

```
{
   "name": "ffftest",
   "pass": "123",
   "mail": "afsdf@awdfasd.com"
}
```

The Drupal user is created immediately, but the HTTP request takes about 240sec to respond. When that finally happens, the response is good: status 200 with the uid/uri.

How do I find out what's going on with the HTTP response and get Services to respond immediately?

(Possibly related to the new CSRF token https://drupal.org/node/2013781#comment-7508325)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a server configuration issue as described here: http://www.promediapublishing.com/blog/2012/07/fixing-a-slow-registration-form-post-on-drupal-7

Comment: Can you expand on your link with details? How does your link fix the problem (it looks like its skipping a DNS lookup) ...