# New User Registration Sequence for Services 3.4?

Tags: 7, users, services

[This comment](https://drupal.org/node/2013781#comment-7508325) outlines a working way to login with the new CSRF token:

1. POST to /rest/user/login (nothing in headers). Construct the $cookie from session name + id
2. GET to /services/session/token (include $cookie in the headers). Save the $token returned.
3. Include $cookie and $token in the headers of subsequent requests of a logged in user.

That sequence works even though the first POST happens without sending the token. (The documentation suggests that the token should be used for any POST requests, which does not work in this case.)

What is a working sequence of **HTTP requests** to **register** a new user account? I'm looking for what requests to make in what order - not implementation code.

UPDATE: To be clear, I'm not looking for the `login` sequence. I need a sequence of requests (similar to login example above) that allow a new user to `*register*` their account.

Failed Attempt with system/connect:

```
1. GET:services/session/token

2. POST:system/connect
      Content-Type: application/json
      Accepts: application/json

3. POST:user/register
      Content-Type: application/json
      Accepts: application/json
      X-CSRF-Token: [token]
      Cookie: [session_name]=[sessid]
      Body: {
               "name":"drupalspec0rVzsWAU",
               "pass":"PYKSItFK",
               "mail":"drupalspec0rVzsWAU@drupalspec.com"
      }
```

The Drupal user is created correctly, but the request in step 3. times out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: to address the change in the question

> I'm looking for what requests to make in what order - not implementation code

You can safely ignore the actual code implementation below - the order of the requests remains the same. In fact, exactly the same as in your original question.

If you're already making requests in the order that you've outlined, you needn't do anything more except provide an actual implementation. I'll leave the code in as an example, and so you can see exactly what order the requests need to be made in. I've stuck some numbering in to make it more obvious; the requests are denoted by 1, 2 & 3.

---

This is a basic PHP (i.e. non-Drupal) example...

First off make a generic function for sending your requests:

```
function send_request($url, array $post_array = array(), $cookie = NULL, $token = NULL) {
  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'googlebot');
  //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, $post_array);

  if (!empty($post_array)) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_array);
  }

  if ($cookie) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
  }

  if ($token) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-CSRF-Token: ' . $token));
  }

  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  return $result;
}
```

**1**. Then make your first call to log the user in:

```
// Login.
$data = array(
  'username' => 'user',
  'password' => 'password',
);

$result = send_request("http://server/endpoint/user/login.json", $data);

try {
  $result = json_decode($result);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  die('Login failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Next get the session name and ID, creating your cookie string to send with subsequent requests:

```
$session_id = $result->sessid;
$session_name = $result->session_name;    
$cookie = $session_name . '=' . $session_id;
```

**2**. Then get a CSRF token, making sure to pass the cookie along:

```
$token = send_request("http://server/services/session/token", array(), $cookie);
```

**3**. Finally you can perform your request to the endpoint you're actually interested in. The cookie and token are injected by the send_request() function.

```
$user = array(
  'mail' => 'test@test.com',
  'name' => 'name',
  // Other relevant properties/fields.
);

$result = send_request('http://server/endpoint/user', $user, $cookie, $token);
```

I haven't tested the user creation endpoint so that might not be the exact structure it needs, but checking the responses for errors should let you know exactly what it's after quite quickly. I get the impression from your question that you're mainly interested in the steps leading up to that last request anyway.

The above is adapted from a basic test script I use, for a production environment you'll want to add more error/sanity checking in there. And the functionality is crying out to be wrapped in a class, and be extended to support PUT/DELETE, but I'll leave that to you :)

Comment: Thanks for the PHP login example, @Clive. I'm actually trying to figure out `user/register` in particular. I'll be working in another language so I'm just looking for the HTTP requests.

Comment: @JoeBeuckman OK...that would be a naked `POST` to the login URL, followed by a `GET` to the token URL with the cookie string as part of the request, followed by a `POST` to the user endpoint containing the cookie, the `X-CSRF-Token` header, and the account data. There's not really anything more that I can say, that workflow just needs to be implemented in the language of your choice. The above PHP should make porting it pretty easy (if you're familiary with php, of course). BTW `user/register` is a synonym for `user/create` so you can use them interchangably

Comment: Actually, I'm not really sure how this doesn't answer your question, could you explain why the implicit order described above is insufficient for your needs? Are you looking for extra info that isn't listed in the question?

Comment: The sequence you provided is for `login` and my question asks about `register`. Good to know that `user/register` is a synonym for `user/create` although they seem like they should be different to me. I'm looking for a way a new user can create their account. They aren't logged in and can't log in until they have an account. I assumed that was `user/register` and I don't understand how to create an account while not logged in.

Comment: Ahh ok, sorry I didn't get that. You probably need to replace the call to login with system/connect, I think that'll get you the session info without logging in. Then proceed as normal with steps 2/3 above. Just on mobile so can't check it out at the mo, will take a proper look later on

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that ASAP. Is that the primary function of `system/connect`?

Comment: Hm, I've been trying various permutations with system.connect and it seems like the problem might be the same timeout issue as in this question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/79448/240sec-registering-new-account-with-services

Comment: Sorry this got away from me - yes, the primary function of system.connect is to return the current user object/session id. The timeout issue is a strange one, not one I've come across before

Comment: Looks like timeout is a configuration issue on one of my servers. Registration is working with GET token + POST system/connect + POST user/register. Could you copy your suggestion about system/connect to a new answer so it's clear?

Comment: This works really well. Although I'm trying to build a javascript-based client, it's good to test the service against something reliable.

Comment: Thanks again Clive - I just voted this up again. The order of 1. and 2. is key.